# Istio Cross Cluster Communication Return 503 UH no_healthy_upstream

Tags: kubernetes, istio, http-status-code-503

There are service A in the K8S cluster A while service B in the K8S cluster B. The two clusters are connected through Istio using remote secret. After Istio injection, all the services in both clusters can call each other between clusters or inside the cluster except service B. Service B can also be called inside the same cluster but 503 no_healthy_upstream is captured in service A's Istio proxy sidecar.

I also tried to use istioctl for troubleshooting. `istioctl proxy-config clusters` contains the service B entry while `istioctl proxy-config endpoints` does not have the service B entry.

Error in Istio proxy:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 UH no_healthy_upstream - "-" "Wget" "some-request-id" "service-b.default.svc.cluster.local:8000" "-" outbound|8000|service-b.default.svc.cluster.local - 10.x.x.x:8000 10.x.x.x:40810 - default "-"
```

Output from `istioctl proxy-config clusters`

```
istioctl proxy-config clusters service-a.default | grep service-b

service-b.default.svc.cluster.local     8000      -      outbound      EDS
```

Output from `istioctl proxy-config endpoints`

```
istioctl proxy-config endpoints service-a.default | grep service-b

(does not return any result)
```

How to troubleshoot this issue step by step?